# Optimize jQuery selector with :first

Tags: jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

I have had this feeling that `$('.class:first')` runs faster than `$('.class')`. So anytime I know there only is one `.class` in the subset, I've used it.

Does `:first` make the query run faster, or is it unnecessary?

Comment: if there is only one `.class` element, it should make no difference. (*more likely to perform worse, in the sense that it must do an additional selection instead of just returning everything*)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/does-first-boost-your-selector

Comment: @jAndy, thanks for the jsperf link. did not know about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually depends on the browser, [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) isn't a CSS selector, it's a jQuery filter - so that requires some extra parsing work...where as `.class` by itself can be handed off to a native browser selector method (e.g. [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) here).

Any of these would actually be faster:

```
$('.class').first()
//or...
$('.class').eq(0)
//or fastest:
$('.class').slice(0, 1)
```

...since they run native code then just take the first entry in that set.

Comment: I thought there were no way to get elements by class, other than iterating over them. Therefor my assumption that `:first` would make it faster. You can actually use CSS selectors with the browser's selector method? I really need to read up on JS.

Comment: @Znarkus - yup, some native methods have popped up over the past few years, somewhat driven by these selector-based frameworks :) And for `:first`...when you think about it, it has to run *last* anyway, since jQuery (or Sizzle rather) needs to apply all other selectors to filter the elements down first, *then* pick the first one (via a position filter inside Sizzle).

Answer (score 2):

If anything, parsing and then running the filter on the `:first` should make it slower. If you're looking for a single element, do:

```
$('.class', context).eq(0)
```

That way you can limit the scope of the search to `context` and just take out the single (or no) item using `.eq(0)`.