# jQuery optimization: Check if an element exists, fast?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, I already know how to check if an element exists by using the length property on the jQuery object returned by a specific selector.

However, internally, this means that jQuery first grabs all the objects and then gets the length. For performance reasons, I want to see if just 1 element exists, I don't need to grab the rest.

How can I do that?

Comment: Assign it a id or a class. And fetch that class alone.

Comment: If you can narrow the scope by providing a context that should speed it up as well.

Comment: I have no idea why this was voted down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See related question: [Optimize jQuery selector with :first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407816/optimize-jquery-selector-with-first)

I've branched off a jsPerf test that compares `$("xxx:first")` with `$("xxx").first()` to see if jQuery is optimized to bail out early from matching when `:first` is used. It doesn't seem be have that optimization:

http://jsperf.com/does-first-boost-your-selector/4

**Update:** `.eq(0)` vs `:eq(0)` behaves the same way.

So, you're probably out of luck. There does not seem to be a more efficient way to pick/check the first match. Unless of course, you have the option to constrain your selector to classes and ids, as others have noted, and as it has also been noted in the other question that I linked to.

Comment: While looking into [@Ryan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376923/jquery-optimization-check-if-an-element-exists-fast/6376984#6376984) for a comment about it, I found [jQuery supporting](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) your conclusion that `:first` doesn't help. They actually suggest doing a purely CSS selector followed by `.filter(":first")` since `:first` isn't helped by the native DOM methods.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to check if an element that is not selected by ID exists, and performance is an issue, I use `document.querySelector()` instead of jQuery.

Unlike `querySelectorAll()`, `querySelector()` only seems to select the first matching element, providing an efficient way to check for the existance of an element.

Example

```
if(document.querySelector('a')){
   console.log('This document contains at least one anchor tag!');
}
```

You can also do this by selecting from a jquery object

```
var element = $('#super_special_element');

if(element.get(0).querySelector('a')){
    console.log('Super special element contains at least one anchor tag!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this improves the performance or not but you can filter, with selectors, to only return the first matched element. Try this?

```
var exists = !$("selector:eq(0)").length == 0;
```

Comment: If the down vote was because I'm wrong then please correct me so that I will know I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You initial answer (before your edit) wasn't answering the question. Now it is.

Comment: First: I didn't downvote. According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) `:first` is equivalent to `:eq(0)`. It also says "best performance" is achieved by "using a pure CSS selector, then [using] `.filter(":first")`". No guarantees, but this would definitely imply that `:first` (and by extension `:eq(0)`) doesn't shortcut anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the element has an id you can just use document.getElementById(id) which is the fastest way to look for any dom element.

Within the dom you can use getElementsByTagName to look for elements by tag name.

For all other cases use JQuery.

```
document.getElementById(id);
document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName(tag);
```